# Progress Indicator can't stop animating when loading from browser back to iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

In my application l have a link which opens a browser (Safari), when clicking back from browser back to the application the `UIActivityIndicatorView` can't stop loading or animating although l implemented it to stop animating.. Any help guys...here is my code

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(_ : UIWebView){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let progressIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    alert.view.addSubview(progressIndicator)

    let views = ["alert" : alert.view, "progressIndicator" : progressIndicator]
    var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[progressIndicator]-(-50)-|", options: [] , metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[progressIndicator]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    alert.view.addConstraints(constraints)

    progressIndicator.userInteractionEnabled = false
    progressIndicator.startAnimating()

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
}


func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView){
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
       progressIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alert controller can’t dismiss because you present view controller with animation and before the animation did complete web view delegate method func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView) is called.

There are 2 Solution for problem

1) Present alert view controller without animation

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion:nil)

2) Dismiss alert controller after some milliseconds delay

let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil) self.progressIndicator.stopAnimating() }

Code Snippet

let progressIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView() let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .Alert)

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(_ : UIWebView) {

alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
alert.view.addSubview(progressIndicator)

let views = ["alert" : alert.view, "progressIndicator" : progressIndicator]
var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[progressIndicator]-(-50)-|", options: [] , metrics: nil, views: views)
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[progressIndicator]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
alert.view.addConstraints(constraints)

progressIndicator.userInteractionEnabled = true
progressIndicator.startAnimating()

// If false then 1 solution will work 
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion:nil)
// If true then 2 solution will work 
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView) {

// 1 Solution 
/*self.alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
self.progressIndicator.stopAnimating()*/

// 2 Solution
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    self.progressIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like the you are referencing to the wrong `progressIndicator` to `stopAnimating()`.

In the above you have a:

```
let progressIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
```

This create a new UIActivityIndicatorView() and you start animating it.

But in the `webViewDidFinishLoad`, there is no way you can get the `progressIndicator` instance from above. I am suspecting that you are referencing to a `IBOutlet` or a class `variable`. Therefore you are telling the wrong `UIActivityIndicatorView()` to stop.

If it is a class variable, in the above code, you should replace it with this:

```
let progressIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()  
progressIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()       //replace above with this
```

If it is a `IBOutlet` that is link to a `UIActivityIndicatorView()` in the storyboard, you should just be calling `progressIndicator.startAnimating()`
without creating a new one. Therefore just remove the `let progressIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()`

Comment: l removed it but still it can't stop animating when loading from the browser

Comment: Could you show me what is your `progressIndicator` at `webViewDidFinishLoad` referencing to?

Comment: @IBOutlet var progressIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

Comment: Then you do not have to `let progressIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()`. This create a new instance of `UIActivityIndicatorView()` instead of using what you have in storyboard. Just remove it totally.

Comment: when l open links within the application it performs well(it starts animating and stops when it opens. when l click on an external link that directs me to the broswer it opens but going back to the application it doesnt stop animating)

Comment: Okay i just saw that you are adding to a `UIAlertController`. In this case, you should not use `IBOutlet`. Change to a class variable. Replace your `IBOutlet` with `let progressIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()`. Then in both places just use `progressIndicator` instead of creating a new one.

Comment: thanks  it worked....it was my url which l was accessing that also had some issues

Answer (score -1):

may be you need to delete UIActivityIndicatorView

```
progressIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
```